# want to fix position of model popup when i scroll background page

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i am working with bootstrap asking about model popup position.i am listing here my model popup information

1) i have model popup. i enabled page background during model popup is open.
2) page background could scroll when at the same time model popup is open.

now problem is when i scroll background page, my  model popup moves with page background. 
now i want to fix model position with text box position which exist in the background. mean when i scroll background model popup should not move. and should not leave it's position.

Answer (score 1):

Please try with below styles

Assuming your modal has outter-modal css class,

```
.outter-modal{
position:fixed;
top:50%;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
```

Comment: my current  css  is .modal-backdrop {
            display: none;
        }  .modal-open {
            overflow: auto !important;
        }when i tried .outter-modal{
position:fixed;
top:50%;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
} not worked and when i try .modal-open {
            position: fixed;
            top: 50%;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        } my background scroll has gone.

Comment: well i want this like fackbook friend search list. like my popup should fix position or associated or bind with text field. and when i scroll down model popup should fix with text field

Comment: Use these style in modal-content, if you use bootstrap

Comment: if i use styling model-content then it will fix position in modal-dialog i want to fix model popup position when i scroll main page background then model popup should not move with page. it should fix

Comment: Can you copy me your div structure it would be better to ans you with the div structure rather than me assuming something and respond